# How to reconstruct a 2D K-by-K square matrix from a 1D vector that contain its upper diagonal element given that the other element are zeros?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I got a vector of numbers with length 6 like this  `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]` and I want to reconstruct the corresponding 4-by-4 matrix `A` like this where all the element from the diagonal to the other lower diagonal are all zero.

```
A = [0 1 2 3
     0 0 4 5
     0 0 0 6
     0 0 0 0]
```

The relationship between the vector `a` and the corresponding matrix `A` is that if the dimension of the matrix is `K` then the length of vector `a` is `K(K-1)/2`. In this case the length of `a` is `6` which mean `K = 4`.

Another example case would be `a = [1 2 3]` then

```
A = [0 1 2
     0 0 3
     0 0 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, just use [`squareform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) and [`triu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html):

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
A = triu(squareform(a, 'tomatrix'));
```

Without the toolbox:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
n = (1 + sqrt(1+8*numel(a)))/2; % size of matrix
A = zeros(n); % initiallize
A((1:n).'>(1:n)) = a; % build logical mask using implicit expansion, and fill the 
% lower half of the matrix with the desired values in column-major order
A = A.'; % transpose to put the values into the upper half in row-major order
```

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh that's a different question. Please stick to a single question per single post, and try something yourself please first.